# How to split Lines using shell SED or something similar

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a file containing the following

```
String, SomeotherString Additional, StringNew String
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
String, Someother
String Additional, String
New String
```

The delimiter is always a capital letter following a small letter without space. I tried
`sed 's/\([a-z][A-Z]\)/\n\1/g <<< String, SomeotherString Additional, StringNew String` However this leads to:

```
String, Someothe
rString Additional, Strin
gNew String
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1\n\2/g'
```

Matches a small letter (sub-expression 1) followed by a capital letter (sub-expression 2) and replaces them with the part matching sub-expression 1, a newline character, and the part matching sub-expression 2.

The previous should work with any sed. With GNU sed and others that support it, you can use `-E` (also `-r` in GNU sed) to enable extended regexps, so that you don't have to put backslashes before the parentheses.

```
sed -E 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1\n\2/g'
```

At least GNU sed also supports [named character classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-named-character-classes), so you can easily match other letters than a-z and A-Z too:

```
sed -E 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/\1\n\2/g'
```

Comment: Ok this was exactly what I needed including a explanation perfectly!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

More than one way to do this, but here's one that uses perl

`echo 'StringSomeotherstringAdditionalString' | perl -pe 's/([A-Z])/\n$1/g'`

`[A-Z]` matches a capital letter;
`\n$1` replaces it with a newline and the capital letter.

Comment: Thanks for that I will specify the example as I made a mistake there not having exact enough information